# Create a entity with existing entity that comes from db

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a new role related existing user with entity that comes from query. I get a entity from db;

```
var user =  GetAll()
           .Include(s => s.User)
               .ThenInclude(a => a.Role)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == userId);//at this point role state is unchanged when i try to update its fields context thinks it is modified.
```

When I try to do this I get an error;

```
var roleEntry = Context.Entry<Role>(user.Role);
        roleEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        user.RoleSetId = null;
        user.Role.Id = 0;
        user.Role.OrganizationId = 5;//other properties of role remains same as db with other navigation properties

        Context.SaveChanges();
```

entity framework core 2.2.4

Error;

> The property 'RoleId' on entity type 'Role' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.

Comment: which version of entityframework you are using. and what error you are facing?? can you also post the error message ??

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil question has been updated according to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to many ways like changing states or another things I found a simpliest way.

```
var role = GetAllRoles()
       .AsNoTracking() //Important thing is here
       .Include(s => s.OrganizationUnits)
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == roleId);
```

These codes create the same entity and relates the relation between role and organizationunit then we can give that roleId to user or another thing. These classes are just example;

```
role.Id=0;
role.Name="Mahmut";
foreach (var organizationUnit in role.OrganizationUnits)
{
    organizationUnit .RoleId = 0;
    organizationUnit .Role= null;
}
context.Add(role);
user.RoleId=role.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are editing an existing user role which is not possible... because it is being used by other users also. you just need to create a new instance of user role

```
user.Role = new Role(){OrganizationId = 5};
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But I am trying to add new one not delete existing role it remains in database and the bond between another entites remains still healty.

Comment: are you trying to add multiple roles to a single user ?

Comment: this code will not delete the existing role.. it will create a new role in database and assign newly created role to the user. also according to your entity structure, you can not assign multiple roles to User

Comment: But I dont want to write all properties again, I just want to change just a few property then create, I already know creating a entity this way.